# Is Firebase client SDK necessary for simple APNS?

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a project that currently sends PNs through APNS and I'm investigating using Firebase for this purpose. I would prefer that the push notifications be sent through APNS and Firebase merely acts as a wrapper/intermediate around APNS. I'm not using any other feature of Firebase(storage, persistent connections, messaging, etc) either.

All guides/examples on this topic seem to integrate the Firebase SDK and relevant config files but I don't see the need for any client side change if the notifications are going to go through APNS.

Do I really need the Firebase SDK for simply sending PNs? If yes, for what reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the Firebase SDK if you intend to use the service.

The behavior of FCM, as you know it, is that when you send a message with FCM, it forwards the message towards APNs, which in turn would send it to the iOS device.

If you're already fine using APNs alone for the push notifications, then you technically don't need the Firebase SDK.